# Connect MySQL configuration with CA certificate?

Tags: swift, ubuntu, vapor

I am using [mysqlkit](https://github.com/vapor/mysql-kit) for Vapor server side project and used to configure MySQL like below:

```
let config = MySQLConfiguration(hostname: "127.0.0.1", port: 3306, username: "root", password: "s3#12412r657f", database: "Admin", tlsConfiguration: nil)
```

It was successfully connected to the local database. Now, I've SSL `CA` file (Certficate Authority file for SSL) for remote database.

> In mysql workbench I selected that ca_cert.crt file on the **SSL tab** at **Path to Certificate Authority file for SSL** field. Works fine!

But I don't know how to configure TLS or where to put my `cacertificate.crt` file & I've tested the crt file is PEM format only.

```
static let prod: MySQLConfiguration = {
    
    var tls = TLSConfiguration.makeClientConfiguration()
      
    do {

        let bytes = [UInt8]("""
        -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
        EX_CERTIFICATE_STRINGS...
        -----END CERTIFICATE-----
        """.data(using: .utf8)!)
        let cert: NIOSSLCertificate = try .init(bytes: bytes, format: .pem)
        tls.certificateChain = [.certificate(cert)]
        tls.privateKey = nil
        let config = MySQLConfiguration(hostname: "192.65.85.577", port: 3658, username: "testadmin", password: "dd#246$@erjt!df^67", database: "Elevate", tlsConfiguration: tls)
        return config
        
    } catch {
        
        fatalError("DB SSL CA Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}()
```

When I query database I'm getting the error that tells,

```
{
    "error": true,
    "reason": "handshakeFailed(NIOSSL.BoringSSLError.sslError([Error: 268435581 error:1000007d:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED at /Users/At4/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Elevate-xcftyy3423/SourcePackages/checkouts/swift-nio-ssl/Sources/CNIOBoringSSL/ssl/handshake.cc:393]))"
}
```

But the same certificate and other parameters works fine with MySQLWorkBench.

Comment: "just need about TLS configuration"  You need what about TLS configuration?  Yesterday, I ignored your topic because you indicated that you accessed a local MySQL server and wanted to know how to work on TLS settings, which didn't make sense.  That's a server-sider job to my knowledge.  If you insist, see Open Transport settings in Info.plist.

Comment: @ElTomato,  Yes it's my mistake that I should edited some random IP address instead of localhost. So I'm using a remote sql database and there is Certificate Authority file for SSL(MySQL workbench works fine with this cert). I've updated the question. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: @ElTomato I fixed it & posted answer, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The crt should assigned to the `trustRoots`:

```swift
tls.certificateVerification = .fullVerification
tls.trustRoots = .certificates([cert])
```

Or It could be connected without certificate verification (unsafe):

```swift
tls.certificateVerification = .none
```